# What does it mean for the hessian to have a value?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

The hessian matrix is the matrix formed by taking the second derivatives of some vector $X$.

$$\nabla^2 X = H$$

In determining whether a function at critical point is a minimum or maximum, we test to see whether the hessian is positive or negative.

Am I correct that to check whether the hessian is positive, we simply check whether all entries of the matrix are $> 0$?

Comment: No, positivity of the Hessian in this context means that all the eigenvalues are positive.

Comment: Three people have answered this or commented on it and so far I'm the only one who's up-voted the question. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Note: The Hessian (as an operator) is not applied to "some vector $X$".  The Hessian is applied to a scalar function.)

I assume you're talking about the second derivative test.  In that case what you're looking for is whether the Hessian matrix is *positive definite*, *negative definite*, indefinite but nondegenerate, or none of the above.

**Definition**: A real-valued symmetric, square matrix is positive (negative) definite if all of its eigenvalues are positive (negative) real numbers.

The second derivative test states:

- If your Hessian is positive definite at a critical point then that
  point is a **local minimum** of your function.
- If your Hessian is negative definite at a critical point then that
  point is a **local maximum** of your function.
- If your Hessian has positive *and* negative eigenvalues (but no
  zeros) at a critical point, then that point is a **saddle point**.
- If your matrix has a zero eigenvalue at a critical point then the test is inconclusive.

---

As some schools require multivariate calculus before linear algebra, if you don't understand the concept of an eigenvalue let me know and I'll give you an alternate criterion for determining positive/ negative definiteness.

Answer (score 1):

Just look at the eigenvalues. If they are strictly positive, then you say that the Hessian (or matrix in general) is positive definite.